# Listview C++ win32 API - Example Not Working

Tags: c++, api, listview, winapi, createwindow

I am trying to create a listview in C++ with the win32 api, however the code supplied on mdsn is giving me an error.

```cpp
HWND CreateListView (HWND hwndParent) 
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;           // Structure for control initialization.
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    RECT rcClient;                       // The parent window's client area.

    GetClientRect (hwndParent, &rcClient); 

    // Create the list-view window in report view with label editing enabled.
    HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, //ERROR red line under create window
                                     L"",
                                     WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
                                     0, 0,
                                     rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
                                     rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                                     hwndParent,
                                     (HMENU)IDM_CODE_SAMPLES, //ERROR IDM CODE SAMPLES undefined
                                     g_hInst, //ERROR
                                     NULL); 

    return (hWndListView);
}
```

This example is strait from mdsn and I have no idea why it is not working. I am getting IDM_CODE_SAMPLES Undefined, and something wrong with createwindow. Please help me to get this working it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`IDM_CODE_SAMPLES` is the ID you want to assign to your control. You can either define the symbol to a numeric value, or use the numeric value directly ([choose 100](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013), for example). The ID is useful if you want to reference a particular control, although its `HWND` is equally useful as an ID.

`g_hInst` is presumably a global variable of type `HMODULE`, initialized from `WinMain`. If you don't want to use the global variable, you can call `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` in its place, provided that you are compiling an .exe as opposed to a .dll.

You'll get a lot of helpful information when working through [Intro to Win32 programming in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/introduction-to-windows-programming-in-c--).

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I am now getting an error (1 unresolved externals) when I try to compile. I'm just trying to get a project working with a listview to see how it works.

Comment: It's very difficult in visual studio 2019, I have made projects work in older ides however I can't seem to get it to work in here.

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1889329)

Answer (score 1):

**I am now getting an error (1 unresolved externals)**

We can find from [InitCommonControlsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex) function.

> Ensures that the common control DLL (Comctl32.dll) is loaded, and
>   registers specific common control classes from the DLL.

Add:

```
#include <commctrl.h>    
#pragma comment(lib,"Comctl32.lib")
```

Minimal code example:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Comctl32.lib")

#define IDM_CODE_SAMPLES 101

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
HWND CreateListView(HWND hwndParent);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );
    CreateListView(hwnd);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND CreateListView(HWND hwndParent)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;           // Structure for control initialization.
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    RECT rcClient;                       // The parent window's client area.

    GetClientRect(hwndParent, &rcClient);

    // Create the list-view window in report view with label editing enabled.    
    HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, //ERROR red line under create window
        L"",
        WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
        rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
        hwndParent,
        (HMENU)IDM_CODE_SAMPLES, //ERROR IDM CODE SAMPLES undefined
        GetModuleHandle(nullptr), //ERROR
        NULL);

    return (hWndListView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is having issues around SysListView32:

```
#include <Ole2.h>
OleInitialize(NULL);
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
BOOL bRet = InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);
...
```

For reference: fully working example with bells and whistles: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/Win32-List-View